# Как разобраться с поиском максимального значения в массиве при помощи reduce?

Tags: javascript

есть массив

```js
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
```

При помощи метода reduce находим максимальное значение

```js
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let c = a.reduce((sum, current) => sum < current ? current : sum);
console.log(c);
```

Как я понял, в теле стрелочной функции записано условие, что если следующий элемент массива больше суммы предыдущих элементов, то этот следующий элемент возвращается и записывается в sum, если меньше, то sum остается.

Вопрос: Правильно ли я понял логику данного метода и зачем в sum записывать current, если current больше sum?

Comment: потому что `sum` - это плохое имя переменной. В данном случае ее лучше было назвать `maxValue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `reduce()` выполняет функцию `callback` один раз для каждого элемента, присутствующего в массиве, за исключением пустот, принимая четыре аргумента: начальное значение (или значение от предыдущего вызова `callback`), значение текущего элемента, текущий индекс и массив, по которому происходит итерация.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].reduce((accumulator, currentValue, index, array) => {}, initialValue);
```

При первом вызове функции, параметры `accumulator` и `currentValue` могут принимать одно из двух значений. Если при вызове `reduce()` передан аргумент `initialValue`, то значение `accumulator` будет равным значению `initialValue`, а значение `currentValue` будет равным первому значению в массиве. Если аргумент `initialValue` не задан, то значение `accumulator` будет равным первому значению в массиве, а значение `currentValue` будет равным второму значению в массиве.

Функция переданная в `reduce()` должна возвращать значение `accumulator` для следущей итерации.

Answer (score 1):

> Как я понял, в теле стрелочной функции записано условие, что если следующий элемент массива больше суммы предыдущих элементов, то этот следующий элемент возвращается и записывается в sum, если меньше, то sum остается.

> Правильно ли я понял логику данного метода?

Нет, логика данного метода другая.

Метод [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) проходит по всем элементам массива, передавая первым параметром в callback результат, полученный на предыдущем шаге.

Простым аналогом данного кода мог стать следующий:

```
var sum = a[0];
for(var i=1; i<a.length; i++){
    var current = a[i];
    if (sum < current){
        sum = current;
    }
}
```

Таким образом, по окончании цикла, в переменной `sum` будет значение максимального элемента.